# simultaneous equation in SageMath

Tags: python, math, sage

Using Sagemath how can I go about solving simultaneous equations:

> x^2 +y^2 +6z^2 = 3
>
> 6x^2 +6y^2 +z^2 = 2
>
> x +y+z = 0

Comment: You mean an equation system? Something like [this](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/8613/solving-a-simple-system-of-equations/)?

Comment: I think its a bit different I need to find the values of x, y,z instead of the final answer

Comment: [This](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/11070/find-algebraic-solutions-to-system-of-polynomial-equations/) is also not what you want? If so, I don't know *what* you want

Answer (score 2):

To make user8408080's answer [more explicit](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrSyzSUK_UqVLX5OUqzs8pS9WIrogzUtCuBBFmWlVAytZWwVhHwUyrAiIEloGKG-lUaFdqV4GYBrE6FTpAgzQBndUVvg==&lang=sage):

```
sage: var('y,z')
sage: solve([x^2 +y^2 +6*z^2 == 3, 6*x^2 +6*y^2 +z^2 == 2,x+y+z == 0],x,y,z)
[[x == -1/70*sqrt(70) + 2/35*sqrt(35), y == 1/70*sqrt(70) + 2/35*sqrt(35), z == -4/35*sqrt(35)], [x == 1/70*sqrt(70) - 2/35*sqrt(35), y == -1/70*sqrt(70) - 2/35*sqrt(35), z == 4/35*sqrt(35)], [x == 1/70*sqrt(70) + 2/35*sqrt(35), y == -1/70*sqrt(70) + 2/35*sqrt(35), z == -4/35*sqrt(35)], [x == -1/70*sqrt(70) - 2/35*sqrt(35), y == 1/70*sqrt(70) - 2/35*sqrt(35), z == 4/35*sqrt(35)]]
```